# Unable to resolve dependency conflict error when dockerizing react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, npm

**When I type:**

```
docker build -t dashboard:latest .
```

It gives this dependency error

```
code ERESOLVE

#9 83.73 npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
#9 83.73 npm ERR! 
#9 83.73 npm ERR! While resolving: react-berry-admin-template@0.0.4
#9 83.73 npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
#9 83.73 npm ERR! node_modules/react
#9 83.74 npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
#9 83.74 npm ERR! 
#9 83.74 npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
#9 83.74 npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-custom-scrollbars@4.2.1
#9 83.74 npm ERR! node_modules/react-custom-scrollbars
#9 83.74 npm ERR!   react-custom-scrollbars@"^4.2.1" from the root project
#9 83.74 npm ERR! 
#9 83.74 npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
#9 83.74 npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
#9 83.74 npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I Used –legacy-peer-deps i.e:

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

but it didn't fix the issue